# What are these event handlers that started appearing in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I'm working on a number of Javascript-heavy applications and do my testing in Firefox.

Because the applications are JS-heavy, I'm pretty aware of what's going on in the `window` scope and try to eliminate as much pollution as possible.

I just recently started seeing a bunch of pointer event handlers appear in the global scope that I **swear** were not there before.

See the below picture:

- Items with red bar are new handlers in question
- Items with green bar are things I've come to expect out of Firefox
- Items with blue bar are things I'm loading in my application

[image: Screenshot of console showing "new" handler methods]

The full list of newly appearing DOM Event Handlers that I've never seen show up before:

- `ongotpointercapture`
- `onlostpointercapture`
- `onpointercancel`
- `onpointerdown`
- `onpointerenter`
- `onpointerleave`
- `onpointermove`
- `onpointerout`
- `onpointerover`
- `onpointerup`

I have checked the developer release notes for [Firefox 25](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/25) up to [Firefox 30](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/30) and none have appeared to add any of these handlers in the `Interfaces/APIs/DOM` or `Javascript` sections.

**What has changed that is now showing these pointer event handlers in the `window` / global scope?**
It's not really a big deal, but I'm confused that this is happening on EVERY website when I don't recall having made any changes.

For what it's worth:

- I'm using Firefox for Ubuntu out of the official repos (meaning it's version 28).
- Firebug is version 1.12.7

Comment: Looks like they want to support [MS PointerEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn433244(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @phenomnomnominal That's the only mention of these types of events that I found on the internet. Which is fine and all if they're adding it, but I can't find the release notes where they say they've added it!

Comment: They're used pretty heavily on Windows Phone - [here's the spec](http://www.w3.org/Submission/pointer-events/)